# incrementation in while false result

Tags: c, while-loop, increment

I am working on a project where I must creat a matrice and initialize it.
So this is what I have done to `init` the matrice :

```
int     levenshtein(char *string1, char *string2)
{
  int32_t       firstWord = strlen(string1);
  int32_t       secondWord = strlen(string2);
  int32_t       matrice[MAXWORD][MAXWORD]; //MAXWORD = 155
  int32_t       i = 0;
  int32_t       j = 0;

  while (i++ < MAXWORD)
    {
      matrice[i][0] = i;
      matrice[0][i] = i;
    }
}
```

So when I print the matrice I should get in `matrice[0][0] = 0`, `matrice[1][0] = 1` etc

But when I print the matrice everything will be good exepte that `matrice[1][0]` it is equal to `MAXWORD`.

But if increment like this it while work perfectly

```
while (i < MAXWORD)
  {
    matrice[i][0] = i;
    matrice[0][i] = i;
    i++
  }
```

Why the  `while (i++ < MAXWORD)` will change the result of `matrice[1][0]` (and only `matrice[1][0]`) after exiting the `while` ?

Comment: Why not use a `for()` loop? That's the normal way to increment a variable through a range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHen you do the increment in the `while()` statement, you're adding `1` to `i` **before** you enter the body of the loop. So on the first iteration, the value of `i` will be `1`, not `0`. That's why you never initialize`matrice[0][0]`.

Moving the increment to the end of the loop means you enter it with the current value. So the first time through the loop `i` will be `0`, not `1`.

A better way to loop through a range of values is with `for`, not `while`:

```
for (i = 0; i < MAXWORD; i++) {
    matrice[i][0] = i;
    matrice[0][i] = i;
}
```

Comment: I understand but the thing I don't is that `matrice[1][0] = MAXWORD (155)` and `matrice[2][0] = 2`

Comment: I don't understand it, either. Is that really the whole function?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the postincrement operator, first reads the value of your variable, and increments it by one after reading the value so in your code, the i variable will be < than MAXWORD when you do the comparison in the while, and will be equal to MAXWORD when enters the while body.

Hope that this will help you.

Comment: How will it be equal to MAXWORD when the code enters the while body? After the first iteration,  it will be `1`, it will _not_ be `155`, it should have been `0`.